# Remove “Windows” Entry from Mac Boot Loader

Tags: mac, windows, startup, catalina, macos

How can I delete the "Windows" option

I have tried several option, but nothing seems to work

I even wipe out the Mac and reinstall macOS Catalina and nothing.

It shows when I connect the USB with macOS Catalina to install

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here, I assume the flash drive is the only external drive plugged into your Mac.

Use the Disk Utility to erase the flash drive. Use the options shown below.

[image]

Next, [transfer the Catalina files to the flash drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).

If you do not want to erase the flash drive, then follow these steps.

1. Open the Disk Utility.
2. From the View pulldown menu on the Disk Utility main window, select `Show All Devices`.
3. Highlight the flash drive.
4. Note the Device. You should see `diskN` were `N` is a integer.
5. In a Terminal application window, enter the following command. Replace `N` with the integer from the previous step.

   ```
   sudo diskutil mount diskNs1
   ```
6. Note the name of the mounted volume. Here, I will assume the name was `EFI`. If you get a different name, make the appropriate substitution when entering the command given below.

   ```
   VOLNAME="EFI"
   ```
7. Enter the following commands.

   ```
   rm -rf "/Volumes/$VOLNAME/EFI/Boot"
   rm -rf "/Volumes/$VOLNAME/EFI/Microsoft"
   diskutil unmount "$VOLNAME"
   ```